How much difference in drag there is between a feathered and non-feathered airplane?
Considering a typical twin like a Beechcraft Baron/Piper Navajo, if you lose both engines and no feathering is done how much drag will you have compared to if feathering was done.
Or in another way, what I really want to know is a rough estimate, about how much (percent wise) will your stall speed increase in a non feathered vs feathered scenario?

One does not have a feathered airplane; one may have a feathered propeller.

A feathered airplane is what we call a "bird".

The increase in drag is quite substantial.  The non-feathered blades continue to spin.  They are connected to the in-operative engine, so the engine keeps turning over.  You continue compressing air like a pump.  The power to keep the pump pumping is taken from your kinetic and potential energy.
All that said, this does not change your stall speed.  There may be a small difference in power on vs. power off stall speed, but this is due to the propeller blowing air (or not) over the wings.
The big difference you will see is in your power off rate of descent.  The increased drag will cause an increased rate of descent -- at whatever speed you're at.

ok. Interesting point about the engine. So, does that means that if the propeller wasn't attached to an engine(just imagine an hypothetical airplane with the propeller unattached to the engine) would you be able to glide a longer distance?

Yes, if you had a propeller that was just free-wheeling, it would extract less power, cause less drag, and you would glide longer.

I'm not sure how much energy the compression is really going to steal. If you don't have a detonation increasing the pressure in the cylinder to add energy to the system or a jake-brake releasing the compressed air to remove energy from the system, the air trapped in the cylinder is just going to act like a spring and push the energy back into the prop on the next stroke. You'll lose some energy to friction but I don't think the compression is going to make you lose any more energy than if you just had the valves all open all the time.

@DarthPseudonym The mechanics of the engine -- crank, cam, valves, etc keep working.  In this mode, the engine compresses a slug of air each stroke and discharges it.  If you've ever turned an engine over by hand -- and then removed the plugs and done it again, you'll realize that the former is much harder.  In many ways, you are engine braking -- but without a dedicated exhaust restriction.

In terms of piloting with a failed engine -- best (least drag) case, feather the prop, it comes to rest.  Worst case, feathering does not work, engine windmills with engine acting as a load.  Intermediate case -- feathering does not work, engine seizes.  The seized engine case actually has less drag than the windmilling case.

@RobMcDonald No, that's what I'm saying. You're only engine braking if you open the exhaust valve and release the compressed air with a pop while the cylinder head is up. That's what a jake brake is. If you don't do that, then all the energy you spent compressing the air is still in the cylinder and will release by making the expansion stroke easier -- the effect is the same as if you put a large spring in the cylinder instead of air. You can't ever recover ALL the energy (thanks, thermodynamics) but the loss from compressing and expanding a sealed container is pretty small.

@DarthPseudonym When I drive my light pickup truck (no Jake Brake, but with a manual transmission), and I down shift and engine brake, I slow down quite rapidly.  Much more rapidly than if I keep the clutch pedal down and coast to a stop.  Even if we ignore the compression / expansion strokes (as a spring), we still have the intake and exhaust strokes that make an engine act like a pump.

Yes, there are more losses when you're using your kinetic energy to move whole load of gears, shafts, and pistons than if you don't do all that. No argument there. I misspoke by saying you were not engine braking if you don't use engine compression braking, I'm only saying the compression of gas in the cylinder isn't a significant energy sink unless you release it to atmosphere while it's under pressure.
